# Promise middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Recently I had to write the strange code. I'm not sure about it, maybe I'm reinventing the wheel.

Is there any simple way to put the middleware into the promise chain?

Assume we have some promise, for example, that may be `axios.get('/users')`.
We want to do something with the result, and then do something else.
Suppose these actions lie in different parts of application, and we can not combine them into one function.
Even more, some of them are just syncronous store updates (and does not return anything), and the other may return promise.

One may write

```
axios
  .get('/users')
  .then((result) => {
    doSomething(result)
  })
  .then((result) => {
    doSomethingElse(result)
  })
```

This won't work because the first `then` does not return a promise, so the second `then` will not receive the result.
The correct code (for syncronous actions without promises) is:

```
axios
  .get('/users')
  .then((result) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doSomething(result)
    resolve(result)
  }))
  .then(result) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doSomethingElse(result)
    resolve(result)
  })
  ...etc...
```

But I don't like this. Am I alone? I would like to have something like:

```
axios
  .get('/users')
  .thenMiddleware(doSomething)
  .then((result) => {
    doSomethingElse()
  })
```

That means we want to run `doSomething` with the result of `get('/users')` and then, if no error, we want to call the next chain function with the result of `get('/users')` again.

About the error: I would consider errors only in case if an action returns a promise, and this promise rejects.

Does it makes sense?

That's the function I wrote:

```
const promiseMiddleware = (target) => function(...args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof target === 'function') {
      target = target.apply(this, args)
    }
    if (typeof target === 'object' && typeof target.then === 'function') {
      // Middleware does not count the result of inner promise, it triggers the promise chain to continue with the incomming data instead.
      // But if the inner promise rejects, middleware returns an inner error.
      target.then((targetResult) => {
        // So we don't use targetResult here, we just resolve with the incomming args.
        resolve.apply(this, args)
      }).catch(reject)
    } else {
      resolve.apply(this, args)
    }
  })
}
```

We can use it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kasheftin/uzmtkfuc/). Is that the right approach or do I miss something obvious about promises that's usable in my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The middleware concept you're looking for is the `then` (or `catch`) callback itself. `then` (and `catch`) return a **new** promise (let's call it `newP`). If the callback you provide to `then`/`catch` returns a promise (or more generally a *thenable*), `thenP` is *resolved to* the one that the callback returns, meaning it will be fulfilled or rejected based on what that promise/thenable does. If the callback returns a non-thenable value (e.g., not a promise), `thenP` is fulfilled with that value. If the callback throws an exception, `thenP` is rejected with that exception.

*(If the term "thenable" isn't familiar, or you're not clear on the distinction between "fulfill" and "resolve," I go into promise terminology in [this post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/) on my blog.)*

> The correct code (for syncronous actions without promises) is

No, the correct code is to return out of `then`:

```
axios
    .get('/users')
    .then(result => {
        return doSomething(result);
    })
    .then(result => {
        return doSomethingElse(result);
    });
```

If it's **just** the function call you can also write it as simply:

```
axios
    .get('/users')
    .then(doSomething)
    .then(doSomethingElse);
```

If `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` are also asynchronous, ensure they return promises. If they aren't, the above works, or you could combine it:

```
// Assumes `doSomething` is not asynchronous
axios
    .get('/users')
    .then(result => doSomethingElse(doSomething(result)));
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> what if `doSomething` does not return any value? Then `doSomethingElse` will not receive the result of `get()`...

One of the chief concepts of promises is that they're a *pipeline*, where each step in the pipeline can potentially transform what's passing through it. If you need a segment in the pipeline that doesn't transform the resolution value, that's fine, just combine it with the next segment (if it's not asynchronous) or have that segment return what it receives (if it is):

```
// (1) If `doSomething` ISN'T asynchronous or it is but you don't care
// that `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` run in parallel if it is
axios
    .get('/users')
    .then(result => {
        doSomething(result);
        return doSomethingElse(result);
    });
```

or

```
// (2.1) If `doSomething` IS asynchronous and you want to wait for it but you
// don't want its result
axios
    .get('/users')
    .then(result => {
        return doSomething(result).then(result);
    })
    .then(result => {
        return doSomethingElse(result);
    });
```

That latter can also be written:

```
// (2.2) Also if `doSomething` IS asynchronous and you want to wait for it but
// you don't want its result
axios
    .get('/users')
    .then(result => doSomething(result).then(result))
    .then(doSomethingElse);
```

Note that both (2.1) and (2.2) will still respect a rejection from `doSomething`. If you want to **completely** ignore what happens in it, then:

```
// (3) If `doSomething` IS asynchronous and you want to wait for it but
// you don't want its result AND you want to ignore rejections
axios
    .get('/users')
    .then(result => doSomething(result).then(result, result))
    // Change is here -----------------------------^^^^^^^^
    .then(doSomethingElse);
```

That converts a rejection into a resolution with `result`.

---

Side note: Remember that one of the rules of promises is that you either return the promise to your caller, or you handle rejections yourself. The above has no rejection handlers, but you'd need them in production code (or you'd need to return the result of the chain to something that will have a rejection handler).

Comment: *(Sorry, couple of typos in there, you may have to hit refresh.)*

Comment: Ok, but what if `doSomething` does not return any value? Then `doSomethingElse` will not receive the result of `get()` anyway.

Comment: @Kasheftin You'll just have to make it return the value, by, say, wrapping it: `(value) => { doSomething(); return value; }`

Comment: @Kasheftin: AKX is basically right, depending on whether `doSomething` is asynchronous and whether you want to wait for its result if so. I've added to the answer to address that question more fully.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple..

If you write the middle-ware, `doSomething` function, then simply make it return the result without mutating it. Such as;

```
function doSomething(result){
  // here i do tons of things with the result but i don't mutate it
  return result;
}
```

Then your code may look like;

```
axios
  .get('/users')
  .then(doSomething)     // this will pass result to the next then
  .then(doSomethingElse) // stage automatically wrapped in a promise
```

By the way you don't need to do like `.then(res => {doStg(res)})` just do like `.then(doStg)`.

However if you don't have any control on the middle-ware `doSomething` function then all you have to do is;

```
axios
  .get('/users')
  .then(res => (doSomething(res), res)) // this will pass result to the next then
  .then(doSomethingElse)                // stage automatically wrapped in a promise
```

Note: Use arrow functions when you have only a few instructions inside. I dislike the braces with arrows and instead prefer the comma operator. So ;

```
res => (doSomething(res), res)
```

is essentially the same as;

```
res => {doSomething(res);
        return res;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are in a Promise chain, you don't have to return a Promise. You only have to return a Promise if you are doing an async call inside the chain.

You can just do

```
axios
  .get('/users')
  .then((result) => {
    return doSomething(result);
  })
  .then((result) => {
    return doSomethingElse(result);
  })
```

Let say you have an async callback style call you should then do

```
axios
  .get('/users')
  .then((result) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      doSomething(result, (err, result) => {
         return err ? reject(err) : resolve(result);
      });
    });
  })
  .then((result) => {
    return doSomethingElse(result);
  })
```